# Submit button doesnt do anything

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

When clicking on submit button after completeing form, it doesnt go to controller post method, the issue is caused by jQuery, but i dont know why. As soon as i remove the script submit button works.

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#brand_Brand_ID").change(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // this will call when Brand Dropdown select change
            var brandID = parseInt($("#brand_Brand_ID").val());
            if (!isNaN(brandID)) {
                var ddModel = $("#Model_ID");
                ddModel.empty(); // this line is for clear all items from Model dropdown
                ddModel.append($("<option></option").val("").html("Select model"));
                // Here I will call Controller Action via Jquery to load Model for selected Brand
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetModels","ModelSpec")",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { brandID: brandID },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {

                            $.each(data, function (i, val) {     
                                ddModel.append(
                                        $("<option></option>").val(val).html(val));           
                            });
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Fail");

                    }
                });

            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

And the html part >

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ModelSpec", FormMethod.Post)) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
 ****Lots of textboxes etc here ****

 <input id="Add" type="submit" value="Add"><br />

  @Html.RouteLink("Continue", new { action = "Create", controller = "ModelSpec" })
  @Html.RouteLink("Back", new { action = "Create", controller = "Model"   })
```

}

Comment: What happens if you exclude the last section `#Add`?

Comment: Nothing really, the problem persists

Comment: Post your HTML, how does your form and button look like? Is the `#add` element the button or link?

Comment: Posted, its submit button

Answer (score 0):

If you calls for the preventDefault for the #Add button click event then the default action of the event will not be triggered, so you are removing the bind of the razor submit event that is the actual post of the razor form.
If you comment this line
        $("#Add").on("click", function (e) {
            //e.preventDefault();
        });
and hit ctrl + F5 to clean browser cache the post of the form should work.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt help